# How to set samesite=none, secure=true in Beego?

Tags: go, samesite, beego

I have to set cookies as `samesite = none` and `secure = true` for my 3D pay URL. I've spent a lot of time trying to solve problem. How can i do it?

simple example for PHP

```
setcookie('cross-site-cookie', 'bar', ['samesite' => 'None', 'secure' => true]);
```

I tried this method in Beego:

```
beego.BConfig.WebConfig.Session.SessionCookieSameSite = http.SameSiteNoneMode
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this would help you:

```
http.SetCookie(c.Ctx.ResponseWriter, &http.Cookie{
                Name:     "sessionid",
                Value:    c.CruSession.SessionID(),
                Path:     "/",
                Domain:   "",
                MaxAge:   86400,
                Secure:   true,
                HttpOnly: true,
                SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode,
            })
```